# StorageCredentials NeedsTransformUri property removed in Azure SDK v2

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I'm upgrading a project from the Windows Azure SDK version 1.7 to 2.1.

I've got some code that uses the `NeedsTransformUri` property of the `StorageCredentials` class:

```
StorageCredentials credentials;

// ....

if (credentials.NeedsTransformUri)
{
    requestUri = new Uri(credentials.TransformUri(requestUri));
}
```

After upgrading my Azure storage references to 2.1, the `NeedsTransformUri` property is no longer part of the `StorageCredentials` class.

How can I tell if I need to call `credentials.TransformUri` in the 2.1 SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always call TransformUri. If it is not needed, it will be a no-op.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected as much, but I couldn't find it documented anywhere I looked.